# Write an insert statement with select clause returning id in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to write a query as follows:

Eg:

```
 DECLARE 
 V_Output varchar(20):='';

 BEGIN
   INSERT INTO T(ID, MY_PK, NAME, VALUE)
   (SELECT ID, NEXT_TRAN_VALUE('T'), NAME, VALUE FROM T WHERE MY_PK = 'NO0000000000013');
   RETURNING MY_PK INTO V_Output;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(V_Output);
 END;
```

using below function

```
create or replace FUNCTION NEXT_TRAN_VALUE (field IN VARCHAR2)   RETURN 
VARCHAR2
IS
n_value   VARCHAR2 (20);
P_APR     VARCHAR2(3);

CURSOR rec_exists IS SELECT * FROM TRANSACTION_SEQ where SEQ_NAME = field ;      
jk_seq_rec  TRANSACTION_SEQ%ROWTYPE;   
PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
SELECT LC_CODE into P_APR FROM LOCATION_CONFIG;
OPEN rec_exists;
FETCH rec_exists INTO jk_seq_rec;

IF rec_exists%FOUND THEN
    UPDATE TRANSACTION_SEQ SET curr_value =   curr_value + 1 WHERE SEQ_NAME = field;
    COMMIT;
END IF;

--SELECT curr_value INTO n_value FROM TRANSACTION_SEQ WHERE SEQ_NAME = field; 
END;
```

But, it shows error.

the select statement shall always return single statement to be inserted, so in my opinion it should return the `my_pk` of inserted row.

Comment: After googling many forums i found that, most people says it is not possible. I should rather store value to local variables and re-insert using them. but, i have many sub-child table linked with each other, so, it will hectic job to do so.

Comment: The function seems rather pointless given that you are losing numbers there just the same as with sequences (because you are committing the update). But a sequence will be a lot faster and will scale much better

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I use `Cursor` to resolve the issue.

Comment: Interesting idea. Could you provide an example? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

That won't work. `RETURNING` clause can't be used the way you're doing it, i.e.

```
insert into t (id, my_pk)
select some_id, your_function from ...
returning into v_output
```

but would work if you inserted `VALUES`, as

```
insert into t
values (id, your_function)
returning my_pk into v_output
```

It means that you'll either have to rewrite that code, or look at a *workaround* described in [returning with insert..select](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=413) article (written by Adrian Billington).

BTW, wouldn't an ordinary Oracle sequence suit your purpose? Won't be gapless, but would be simple & effective. Mind the performance when inserting huge amount of data, using your solution.

BTW #2, what's the purpose of the last line in your function? You never use N_VALUE.

Comment: yes, the oracle sequence suit the purpose, and using this function is rather pointless. but, when i migrate the database to another machine the oracle sequence restart the sequence and create the headache for me(it find the lowest minimum missing value and start the sequence from their.), and their the function comes into play. And last line the use of N_Value is nothing. its just lazy coding.

Comment: How do you mean, "migration resets the sequence"? What kind of a migration is it? Anyway, I'd rather drop the sequence on a new machine and recreate it (using the `start with`, which would be old system's `currval + 1`). Yes, it requires 2 additional statements (`select` and `create sequence`), but will pay off in the future.

Comment: I am new to oracle database. i find `nextval` as the only option to increase value, i didn't come across `currval + 1`, may be it resolve my problem. but i find to have a function to be worthy at that time. Also, neither of them are useful for my current problem.

Comment: OK, no problem. I'm just sharing my opinion, you don't have to accept it.

Comment: @Littlefoot Is there a work around when one is restricted to use `select` instead of `values`?

Comment: Perhaps. If possible, create a local variable, put the ID (sequence number?) into it, and use that local variable in the `insert into` statement. Then you wouldn't have to `return` anything as you'll already have that value stored in the local variable.